# How to use a NavigationLink inside a trailing closure of a view?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I have `List` like below,

```
struct ListItemView: View {
    let vm: ListItemViewModel
    var callHandler: ((ListItemViewModel) -> Void)?
    var textHandler: ((ListItemViewModel) -> Void)?

    HStack {
       Text("Click Me")
    }

}
.swipeActions(allowsFullSwipe: false) {
    
        Button {
            textAction()
        } label: {
            Label("Go", systemImage: "text.bubble.fill")
        }
        .tint(.green)

}

private extension PhoneItemView {

    var callAction: () -> Void {
        return {
            callHandler?(vm)
        }
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to trigger a `NavigationLink` when swipe action is pressed. My `ContentView` looks like this.

```
 List{
        ForEach(viewModel.data) { item in
        
           ZStack {
                        
                     NavigationLink(destination: CallDetailView())
                     .{EmptyView()}.opacity(0.0)
                        
                     PhoneItemView(vm: log, callHandler: { _ in
                         print("swipe action tapped")

                          NavigationLink(destination: DetailView())                                       
                          { EmptyView() }
                     })
                        
            }
        }
}
```

But, even-though the log 'swipe action tapped' gets printed. `DetailView` is not loaded. Also, there's an warning on the `NavigationLink` of `DetailView`.

```
Result of 'NavigationLink<Label, Destination>' initializer is unused
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `NavigationLink` is a `View` that triggers a navigation action when tapped. It isn't just a `Void` closure that you can execute a demand. You need to add the `NavigationLink` to your View hierarchy, you can't create it inside a void closure.

If you want to trigger navigation conditionally, you need to be using the `NavigationLink` initialiser which takes an `isActive` `Binding` instead and set the `Binding` to `true` when you want to trigger the navigation link.

```
@State private var navigateToDetailView: Bool = false

List {
  ForEach(viewModel.data) { item in

    ZStack {

      NavigationLink(destination: CallDetailView())
        .{EmptyView()}.opacity(0.0)

      PhoneItemView(vm: log, callHandler: { _ in
        print("swipe action tapped")
        // Set the binding to true to trigger navigation
        navigateToDetailView = true
      })

    }
  }
}
// Add the NavigationLink to your view
.background(
  NavigationLink(
    destination: DetailView(),
    isActive: $navigateToDetailView
  )
  {
    EmptyView()
  }
)
```

If you want to be able to handle more than one destination, you just need to modify your `@State` to be an optional enum, representing your destination view. Your `isActive` `Binding` also has to change so that it is active in case your `enum` has a non-nil value.

```
struct ViewWithMultipleConditionalDestinations: View {
  private enum Destination {
    case one
    case two
  }

  @State private var destination: Destination?

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      VStack {
        Button("Destination one") {
          destination = .one
        }

        Button("Destination two") {
          destination = .two
        }
      }
      .background(
        NavigationLink(
          destination: destinationView,
          isActive: Binding(get: { destination != nil }, set: { if !$0 { destination = nil } }),
          label: { EmptyView() }
        )
      )
    }
  }

  @ViewBuilder
  private var destinationView: some View {
    switch destination {
    case .none:
      EmptyView()
    case .one:
      Text("One")
    case .two:
      Text("Two")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! How do I handle this if I have two types of destination views. Eg: DetailView, SummaryView. Depending on the type of the log, direct the user to the relevant screen. Is that possible with the above workflow as well?

Comment: @RyanAluvihare yes, see my updated answer for that scenario

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. One last request, Could  you please update the answer where it shows how to pass a parameter to the destinationView?

Comment: @RyanAluvihare StackOverflow is not ChatGPT, where you can keep adding more and more requirements to your questions after you've received a solution matching your previous requirements. If you have additional requirements, ask a new question. But first, you should try to adapt the answer you got to your new requirements.